# Getting exceptions when running basic orleans application

Tags: c#, .net, cloud, distributed, orleans

I'm involved in a IoT project and considering orleans as a platform. I tried to do the basic tutorial here:
http://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Step-by-step-Tutorials/Minimal-Orleans-Application

It seems to be working but I'm getting the following exceptions in the console which would be nice to get rid of:

> Could not load file or assembly 'OrleansCodeGenerator' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Exception =
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'OrleansCodeGenerator' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.
>
> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm using orleans version 1.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a know issue on the template packages. Could you please add the Nuget **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions** version 1.0.0-rc1-final on the Silo host Project? For the other exception, looks like are missing the OrleansCodegenerator package. Could you please ensure that .Server nuget is on Silo Host, .Client on Client/FrontEnd and .Core in Interfaces/Grain project? I think it will work otherwise, feel free to open an issue on https://github.com/dotnet/orleans and we will have a look.

**More info**

The reason this dependency is not added by default as a OrleansCodegenerator dependency, is that this package is not published as a stable package (it is marked as pre-release) and we can't have pre-release packages on Orleans packages otherwise, we would must release Orleans packages as -pre packages. As soon as this package is published as release we are going to update Orleans packages to contain it.

Comment: Hi @Gutemberg, Thanks for your reply. The second exception went away after your suggestion. But the first one regardgin OrleansCodeGenerator still remains

Comment: Hello @jopa. Just edited my answer, please give it try and let me know if it work. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have reference to a package called OrleansCodegenerator  both in the grainsInterfaces and grainscollection projects. Also the Orleans package is there. Besides these projects I have only the host project where my silo host and client is. A pretty simple setup.  I got it finally to work by adding the serv and client nuget packages to my host. I must say, it's a bit confusing to know which packages that are needed

Comment: The OrleansCodeGenerator message went away by adding just the Microsoft.Orleans.Server package to the host project. I agree with jopa, this is a bit confusing. It would be nice if someone updated the instructions on the "Minimal Orleans Application" tutorial to include this extra package. Anyways, Thanks for the help!